# myqsli -> fetch TO pdo

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mysqli, fetch

i need to change this mysqli to to working PDO:

```
$user = "name";
$pass = "password";
try {
   $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname', $user, $pass);
   $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
   die();
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$sth->execute();

    while ($user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        echo $user[1];

    }
```

Using this fetch i dont get the expected result..
but this doesnt work, anybody could check it?
greetings

Comment: Can you describe what you meant by not getting expected result ? What are you getting & what exactly you expecting ?

Comment: Are you getting errors? how are you constructing PDO (`$dbh = new PDO(/*what arguments here?*/);`)

Comment: i need to echo the usernames from the table

Comment: Since you didn't show the `echo` code, how can we tell what you're doing wrong there?

Comment: i edited, in the second column of the table usernames are listed, thats why $user[1], could you refer to it?

Comment: You removed the `mysqli` code from your question! How is someone supposed to know what `this mysqli` refers to?

Comment: @user3122124: Please take a look at my, belated answer: Its more sort of [code-review stuff](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), but you may find it useful to keep a thing or two of what I explain in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you setting $dbh to null?

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname', $user, $pass);
$dbh = null; <--remove this line.
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. No wonder you're getting errors, you're instantly destroying the connection you just set up!

Answer (score 0):

It should be either:

```
while ($user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $user['username']; // Put the actual column name here, I'm just guessing
}
```

or:

```
while ($user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    echo $user[1];
}
```

`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` is like `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, and `PDO::FETCH_NUM` is like `mysqli_fetch_row`.

Comment: ok but why do i get this:  Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /www/htdocs/w011622a/testo/test.php on line 28...for this code: $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");   you know why?

Comment: Because you have `$dbh = null;` after you open the connection.